# How can I fix TWebBrowser memory leak in one-line program? Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, twebbrowser

There have been many answers over the years about memory leaks and the TWebBrowser component, none of which helped me. I simplified the problem to one line of code.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate2('https://www.quora.com/profile/kevin-davidson-9/log');
```

The project has one TWebBrowser on a form and one button with that line of code. Every time I click the button I lose 30-40 mb of memory as measured by Task Manager.

Things that don't work:

- Calling CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx(0, 0);
- Adding navNoHistory + navNoWriteToCache + navNoReadFromCache flags to the Navigate2 call
- Freeing the TWebBrowser
- Navigating to about:blank

The particular page I'm navigating to generates content dynamically as one scrolls down and that is why I'm using the TWebBrowser that I know how to scroll programmatically. If there is a better approach than TWebBrowser, I'm open to that, so long as I can scroll and get the HTML.

Comment: What kind of leak is it? Do you get the memory back when you free the control? Is it reported by `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True`?

Comment: What happens when you replace the button click by a TTimer OnTimer to load the page automatically, for example every second. Is memory seen in task manager stabilize after some time or does it grow forever until Windows crash because of lack of memory? Does the memory leak occurs with that specific page or does it occurs with ANY page?

Comment: The actual application that's failing  uses a timer. I just simplified this to a button. It doesn't happen with just any page, but with the particular example I provided.

Comment: No, I don't get the memory back if I free the TWebBrowser.

Comment: @KevinDavidson did you already check with `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`: set this in you dpr file to `true`, run the application and do your tests and then close the app. When you don’t get a message there is no ‘real’ memory leak...

Comment: So I pressed the button a bunch of times and Task Manager reported the memory usage growing until it hit 1.6 GB and the application just winked out and was gone. I did it a few times with   ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True; and got nothing on a normal close.

Comment: When I put   ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True; in my actual application, one that accesses the text and scrolls the document, I did see leaks  after a short time: 13-20 bytes x 80, 21-28 bytes: UnicodeString x 5, Unknown x 38, 29-36: UnicodeString x 480, 69-76: TStringList x 3, 269-284: Unknown x 1, Medium/large 2860, 4652.

Comment: `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` tracks memory allocated by Delphi itself, not COM components.

Comment: As an alternative, you could try embedding Chromium via [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi).

Comment: I think most of the reported memory leaks are because I had some unit string variables, plus the string lists that are just global parameter storage. The should only be freed when the program ends.

Comment: @R.Hoek: Actually, there may be. In addition to Olivier's point, consider this: suppose you create a new form every time the user wants to display an image. Every time the image form is closed, it should be freed. But the programmer forgets this, so the memory usage increases during the lifetime of the app as the user opens and closes picture viewers. Eventually the program will crash. But all these forms are created with the main form as their owner, so all 5123 forms created during the app's lifetime will be freed on shutdown. Hence you get no reported leak, but there is still a "real" leak!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes, off course there might be memory allocated in such a way. But it still is referenced memory which will be freed when the program closes. At least these kinds of memory ‘leaks’ can be solved, as you have a reference somewhere to that memory. The hard part is finding which referenced memory should/could have been freed 

Comment: I don't think this is a memory leak that is caused by your application but instead a memory leak that is caused by bad code of the mentioned Website. I can recreate this increasing memory consumption in Internet Explorer itself. Granted moving down repeatedly on automatically expanding web page will consume more and more memory as basically the size of the web page is constantly increasing. But normally when you navigate to sme other site the memory is released. Well not in case of Quora website so I'm guessing the cause might be in one of its scripts and how it reserves needed memory

Comment: When I recreate such test in Google Chrome navigating to other site does seem to release the reserved memory. So it seems the problem might lie in the way how Quora reserves memory in IE. And since TWebBrowser is just a wrapper for IE I'm guessing Oliver's suggestion for using Chromium might be best solution for you.

Comment: Because this isn't a commercial program, I can tolerate a rough solution. What I decided to do is for the program to monitor its Working Set memory, and when it gets too large, just exit. Another program on a timer spots that it isn't running and starts it again. I can't ask Quora to fix anything because they already say not to use IE.